# simulate keyboard events like Keyup and keydown in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

How to simulate keyboard events like Keyup and keydown in UWP app.I do not want to use manual keyboard instead i have made my own keyboard but i want to add now keyboard events in it.
I did not find any way in uwp and SendKeys.Send() method is also not available for UWP.

Comment: What do you mean by "made my own keyboard"?

Comment: I mean to say I created simple keyboard programmatically with alphabets and numbers.

Comment: Then why don't you use Events from that control? Attach your code in the question

Comment: I just created keyboard by using button control in XAML and its implementation is in C#.
private void Letter_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)//Button tapped event
        {
     Keyboard implementation logic       
     }

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Suppose if I tapped A button of keyboard to enter 'A' character in textbox at that time I want to generate keyboard event manually say KeyPressed or Keyup,KeyDown like event.For that purpose i have gone through SendKeys class but SendKeys class is not available in uwp

Comment: Had you looked into InputInjector? This seems like the solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/input-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not want to use manual keyboard instead i have made my own keyboard but i want to add now keyboard events in it. I did not find any way in uwp and SendKeys.Send() method is also not available for UWP.

For your requirement, you could create custom event handler to simulate keyboard `KeyDown` ,`KeyUp` event in your custom User Control. The key point is when to invoke your custom event handler. I have create a sample simple you could have a reference.

**CustomKeyBoard.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="UIKeyBoardTest.CustomKeyBoard"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UIKeyBoardTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:control ="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <GridView  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick"  IsItemClickEnabled="True">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid  MaximumRowsOrColumns="3" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40"  Width="55" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <x:String>1</x:String>
            <x:String>2</x:String>
            <x:String>3</x:String>
            <x:String>4</x:String>
            <x:String>5</x:String>
            <x:String>6</x:String>
            <x:String>7</x:String>
            <x:String>8</x:String>
            <x:String>9</x:String>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**CustomKeyBoard.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class CustomKeyBoard : UserControl
{
    public delegate void BoilerLogHandler(string value);

    public event BoilerLogHandler BoilerEventLog;

    public CustomKeyBoard()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BoilerEventLog != null)
        {
            BoilerEventLog(e.ClickedItem.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
 <TextBox x:Name="box" PlaceholderText="Please input something" Margin="0,50,0,60" />
<local:CustomKeyBoard
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    BoilerEventLog="CustomKeyBoard_BoilerEventLog" />

private void CustomKeyBoard_BoilerEventLog(string value)
{
    box.Text = value;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to trigger a Windows shortcut, e.g. Windows Key with another key?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how to simulate keyboard events. For example, I'm running into the same problem with my application, because entering text into fields has special functionality that needs to be reprogrammed (like text box selection index behaviour and key event detection by a web view).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Input Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/input-injection). The documentation has a complicated example, but it basically breaks down into declaring a capability and writing something like the following code:

```
        _inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
        var input = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
        input.VirtualKey = value;
        input.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;
        _inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { input });
```

Where `value` is either a `VirtualKey` or a `char` that can be cast to one. More details in [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56685846/4682228).