# How to Inject Keyboard Input of Multiple Keys with Code in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Trying to simulate the pressing of a Tab and Shift+Tab (Reverse Tabbing) keys with functions in the Code Behind so they can be used with Buttons or in this case other keys on the keyboard.

Got the Simulating of Tabbing working, I am just not sure how to simulate the press of 2 keys simultaneously to simulate the Shift+Tab

```
        private void Tab(string s)
        {
            InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
            var info = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
            if (s == "Right")
            {
                info.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Tab);
            }
            else if (s == "Left")
            {
                //This doesn't actually exist, but How would I do this?
                info.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.ShiftTab);
            }

            inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { info });
        }

        private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {
                case VirtualKey.Number1:
                    Tab("Left");
                    break;
                case VirtualKey.Q:
                    Tab("Right");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

So far the Tab works fine when the Q key is pressed, I just need to find out how to do the Shift+Tab for when the Number1 key is pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. After some help from another user in a similar question, the easiest way to do simulate a multiple button press is as follows:

```
            InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
            var shift = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
            shift.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Shift);
            shift.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;


            var tab = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
            tab.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Tab);
            tab.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;
            inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { shift, tab });
```

In this example I use SHIFT+Tab.

Answer (score 1):

They're called `Modifiers`

`VirtualKey` + `VirtualKeyModifiers`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyboardaccelerator.Modifiers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.virtualkeymodifiers

If you want to use `InputInjector` look into `ScanCode`'s as they represent unique identifies for keys on the keyboard- now they might not be the same for all keyboards- but shift key should be the same. I attached a list of common ScanCodes- read the ScanCode to see what value it gives you. InputInjector takes an array so just path both codes you want to inject or find the combined ScanCode

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.injectedinputkeyboardinfo
https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html

Try ScanCode for Shift-Tab as 0F

Comment: So I changed the ``info.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.ShiftTab);`` into ``(ushort)(VirtualKey.Tab) + (ushort)(VirtualKeyModifiers.Shift)`` but that doesn't seem to have the desired effect. Could you include an example of how to use it properly?

Comment: I don't have a lot of time to write an example. But they exist here https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=VirtualKeyModifiers&type=Code . Github search is your friend :) Please let me know if you are still having trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. First off, I did not know about github search so that will be awesome for the future of my project! However, I wasn't able to find code relevant to my issue. There was only 51 results for "InputInjector" in C# and none that tried to inject multi-key combinations. I am in not rush on this particular issue if you ever get time to get an example for me. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @BWhelan I updated my answer with information that might resolve your issue

Comment: I tried ``info.ScanCode = (ushort)0F;`` and I don't think it does anything

Comment: I think you have to set the KeyOptions as well to ScanCode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.injectedinputkeyoptions

Comment: Sorry, I was testing to see if I could get it working, after setting ``info.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.ScanCode;`` It didn't seem to work but I found another solution that works https://pastebin.com/fCiMfpGb. You seem to be able to combo keys together this way. The only issue I experienced was the Shift key seems to get stuck for my whole computer session after using this syntax. ie all type is caps, clicking around selects everything like Shift+Click would. Is that a bug with my code or a bug with VirtualKeys?